# JQuery scroll entire page at specific speed

Tags: jquery, scroll

There are a ton of questions about scrolling to specific elements or scrolling specific distances with set times. But I'd like to have the entire body scroll at a set rate (ie pixels per millisecond) rather than over a set period of time. Think movie credits rather than a navigation tool.

For example, if I have this page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This will scrolls slowly but stops after 5 seconds.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('html, body').offset().top }, 5000);
  });
```

Rather than specify a duration, I'd like to specify the speed and have the entire body scroll until it hits the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to achieve this is to divide the height of the element over speed (pixels per milliseconds). Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const height = $("body").outerHeight();
  const pixels = 2;
  console.log(height / pixels);

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('html, body').height()
  }, height / pixels);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>
  <p>A lot</p>
  <p>of content</p>
  <p>that I</p>
  <p>want to</p>
  <p>scroll through</p>
  <p>very slowly</p>
  <p>at a</p>
  <p>set rate.</p>

</body>
```